# I was wondering if there's a way to get rid of the white background on Tkitner widgets making it transparent

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

This is how it looks and i was wondering if there's a way to make the white background if this widget transparent so its just the button.

Comment: No, there is no way.

Comment: Are you asking about the think white/grey area _surrounding_ the button? Or, are you asking how to remove the 3d border so that  you only have the text?

Comment: @BryanOakley Keep the button but get rid of the white thing around the shadow if you know what i mean